# Construct new pandas Dataframe with multi level index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new Dataframe with a multi index.  I load a list with the dates for the first level and have a list of patients for the second level.  I can't grasp the method for constructing the proper Dataframe structure...  Basic code.

```
factor_index = pd.date_range(start=startDate, end=endDate)
factor_index.name = 'Date'
factorData = pd.DataFrame(index=factor_index)
```

this creates the frame with the dates as the primary index...  I need to set a second index for each of the dates that lists the patients under each date.  I have a list of patients.  It seems like there's a one-liner for this but I can't seem to find it in my searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
list_of_patient = ['a','b','c']
factor_index = pd.date_range(start=startDate, end=endDate)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([factor_index, list_of_patient], names=('Date','Patient'))
factorData = pd.DataFrame(index=mux)
```